# create dynamic dropdown(s) with mustache

Tags: javascript, mustache

I have the following structure:

```
[
 "key 1": [ "val1", "val2", "val3" ],
 "key 2": [
  "key 3": [ "val4" ],
  "key 4": [ "val5" ]
 ]
]
```

I want to generate dropdowns from this. "key 1"...would be the selectable names, "val1"... the values.
If there is a sub array on the selected key I want to dynamically create another dropdown with those values until the sub arrays just have one value. (like in case "key 2")

I have no idea how to go on this with mustache.
I can get all the keys of the first level into a flat array with `Object.keys` but I can't even generate the first dropdown. Let alone that I have any idea how to go with the other part.

It would be nice to get a general direction as to how it could be done.

Here is some sample code:

```
  const view = {
    files: getFiles(),
    "keys": function() {
      return Object.keys(this);
    }
  };

    <form>
      <select id="selector">
        <option>choose...</option>
        {{#files}}
          {{#keys}}
          <option value="">{{.}}</option>
          {{/keys}}
        {{/files}}
      </select>
    </form>
```

Here is a wireframe, the top is the first case when selecting `key1`, the bottom is when selecting `key2`.
[image]

Comment: Can you sketch use the output you want from that array? I don't understand the nested key 2 with sub-selects with one item each.

Comment: It's just like a file tree. Files you can select, folders you can go one level deeper. Does that help?
Key1, 3 & key4 are folders that have selectable files in them. Key2 is a folder that has subfolders.

Comment: I made a wireframe here: https://wireframe.cc/wzpuw3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/) is a `logic-less` template syntax because there are no if statements, else clauses, or for loops. Instead, there are only tags. Some tags are replaced with a value, some nothing, and others a series of values.

So you cant update the rendered HTML based on the selected value with `mustache`.

Here I'm using `onchange` event to dynamically create the select based on the previous selected value using plain Javascript without `mustache` template

```js
var data = {
  "key 1": ["val1", "val2", "val3"],
  "key 2": {
    "key 3": ["val4"],
    "key 4": ["val5"]
  }
}

function renderSelect(obj) {
  var array = Array.isArray(obj) ? obj : Object.keys(obj)
  var options = ['Choose', ...array].map(i => "<option>" + i + "</option>").join('')

  var select = document.createElement('select')
  select.innerHTML = options
  if (!Array.isArray(obj)) {
    select.onchange = function() {
      // remove next siblings
      var sib = [], el = this
      while (el = el.nextElementSibling) sib.push(el)
      sib.forEach(el => el.remove())
      // render select based on value
      renderSelect(obj[this.value])
    }
  }

  document.querySelector('form').insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', select);
}

renderSelect(data)
```

```html
<form></form>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
function process() {
  var template, data, html;
  template = $('#template').val();
  eval( $('#data').val() );
  html = Mustache.render( template, data );
  $('#html').text( html );
  $('#result').html( html );
}
</script>
```

Now attach this plugin

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="mustache.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="mustache-demos.js"></script>
```

1. Extracts #template textarea.
2. Calls eval() with data object.
3. Calls Mustache.render()
4. Inserts #html textarea.

Output

[image]